# How to have rSync only transfer final folder?

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

Hey all, I don't know how to properly phrase this but when I run (ignore $DESTINATION):

```
rsync -avz tmp $DESTINATION
```

it will transfer the full path of tmp. So save if tmp is in /root/tmp instead of putting just tmp in my destination folder it puts the full path of /root/tmp or wherever it is located... is there a way around this? I just want to put the specific directory and everything in it... not the path above it as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `-R` to use relative file names.